# How to move the last line to the next page?

Tags: page-breaking

I have a trivial (I hope) problem. I want to move the last line from the even page to the odd one and not to break the paragraph. I tried `\newpage` and it moved the line to the odd page but it broke the paragraph too. Then I tried `\pagebreak[1]` but my text floated (vertically) to the bottom even though i used `\raggedbottom` in my preamble (by the way I wouldn't like to use `\raggedbottom`).

I googled and found maybe `changepage` package could help. I used it but my footer moved up and of course I don't want it.

I hope it's clear.
Do you know what to do?

Comment: I think you mean to move "the last line from **an** even page" to the next odd page, don't you? Did you tried `\enlargethispage{-\baselineskip}`?

Comment: A `\newpage` _before_ the line which should move to the next page should definitively work! If it doesn't, then you have something special, which you should show in an example.

Comment: Martin, thanks a lot! It works great! Yes, I ment "the last line from an even page to the next odd page". :)

Comment: Herbert, \newpage works, but it makes another paragraph and I don't want it. I want to make a break inside paragraph.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can enlarge or reduce the current page using the following command. To add or remove a line use `\baselineskip` (the distance between two lines, i.e. their baselines) as reference:

```
\enlargethispage{-\baselineskip}
```