# How to move the last line to the next page while still aligned to the bottom?

Tags: page-breaking

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11045), the accepted answer suggested to use `\enlargethispage{-\baselineskip}` for moving the last line to the next page.

However, the situation I'm encountering is that a long footnote near the last of the second page forced that page to stop earlier, and since in the book it is set to be aligned at bottom of the page, the second page looks a lot emptier than the first page. In this case, I would like to move the last line of the first page to the next page so that they look more even -- but in the mean time still keep them aligned at bottom.

Below is a MWE. As you can see, vertical space between the paragraphs on the second page has been stretched. In this case, can we move one or two line(s) from the previous page so that the two pages on the left and right seem more even?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\blindtext[5]

\blindtext[4]\footnote{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With long paragraphs you can almost always choose a different set of linebreaks, here `\looseness=2` asks tex to try to make that paragraph 2 lines longer, which gives the page breaker chance to break the page without stretching `\parskip`

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\blindtext[5]

\looseness=2
\blindtext[4]\footnote{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. However in the actual document it is mostly short paragraphs (in contrast to the MWE) so changing `\looseness` doesn't seem to help much. Is it possible to achieve a similar result to `\enlargethispage{-\baselineskip}` but with the bottom aligned? (slightly stretched `\parskip` is acceptable to me, but it is important to make the left page and right page as evenly stretched as possible).

Comment: @Jinwen you can force the page break a line earlier simply by adding `\pagebreak` on the last line you want on the page. Hard to do here as you have generated text that makes it hard to add commands mid paragraph